# Как поставить файл на крон

Tags: linux, crontab

Здравствуйте. Есть сервер на линуксе, и есть Shell-клиент. какую команду нужно выполнить чтобы php файл выполнялся каждый 30 минут? файл лежит по пути:
`/var/www/www-root/data/www/site.ru/folder/folder2/info.php`

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужна где то такая команда

```
0/30 * * * * php /var/www/www-root/data/www/site.ru/folder/folder2/info.php
```

Но может так случайно оказаться, что php бинарь либо недоступен для крона (тогда нужно указать полный путь вида `/usr/bin/php`, `whereis php` подскажет) или бинарь `php` называется немного по другому (`php7`, `php-cli` или что то новенькое -  у меня оно называется `/usr/bin/php7.1`).

Но может лучше будет дергать этот скрипт curl'ом через вебсервер. Это можно оказаться удобнее.